# Android SDK: How to set up old versions? eg. gingerbread

Tags: android-emulator

my goal here is to run an android emulator with various old versions of Android to test web apps. I am an android newbie. I have a Nexus 7 with Jellybean. The bugs on the web apps are reported in older versions.

So far I have;

Installed Android SDK on a Windows 8 desktop, created and run emulators but it's limited to Android 4.2 only (Jellybean)

I think the next step is to run the SDK Manager -- Ecplipse > Window > Android SDK Manager

Doing this reports that the Manager will show shortly -- nothing happens. In the console I get this error;

`[2013-02-09 16:31:49 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] \adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe was unexpected at this time.`

Running find_java.exe from the command line gives:

`D:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64>sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe`

`D:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64>where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`

I have updated the PATH environment var to include the jre7 directory as above, and added a ANDROID_SDK_HOME as D:\Users\myuser_000\Documents\Workspace -- devices I create appear in a .android\avd sub-directory.

I am running the SDK on Windows 8, installed in D:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64

Is running the SDK Manager the correct action?

Any ideas what would cause the SDK Manager not to display?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the android.bat file.

I edited the following to comment out the call to find_java.bat and hard coded to my installed version of Java.

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java"
rem call lib\find_java.bat
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Something that may have complicated the issue was windows 8 catching android.bat as an unsafe program and automatically stopping it. I saw this when manually trying to run the batch file.